# Even created a global class, still cannot save a variable from try-catch

Tags: java, json, try-catch

Android Studio topic

My story flow:

1. Created a `GlobalClass` for saving user info.
2. Login to a Facebook account to draw user info (`JSONobject`).
3. In an inner class (`onSuccessListener`), I want to save user name in my `GlobalClass` for later use.
4. AndroidStudio requests me to use `try-catch` for JSON exception. OK, I must use one then.
5. What I do is: try-(Draw user name from JSONObject when login success and save the user Nickname in GlobalClass) and catch-(exception). Done.

However, wherever outside the `onSuccess` inner class, my `GlobalClass` is `null`!

Any ideas?

updated with code: the "globalVariable.setGlobalUserFacebookName()" will have no value when leaving, for other user information, it can save.

```
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            @SuppressLint("StringFormatMatches") String tempText = String.format(getString(R.string.loginInformation,
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(),
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken(),
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().toString()));
            fbtoken.setText(tempText);

            globalVariable.setGlobalUserFacebookID(loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
            globalVariable.setGlobalUserFacebookToken(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            globalVariable.setGlobalUserFacebookPermission(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().toString());


            final String FirebaseEmail = globalVariable.getGlobalUserFirebaseEmail();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {// Application code

                            try {
                                FacebookUserName = (String) response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                                // the value of this globalClass null after leaving this inner class 
                                globalVariable.setGlobalUserFacebookName(FacebookUserName);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            loggedInView.setText(FacebookUserName);

                        }

                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "name");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

public class GlobalClass {

```
private static GlobalClass instance;
private static String globalUserFirebaseName;
private static String globalUserFirebaseEmail;
private static String globalUserFirebasePassword;
private static String globalUserFacebookName;
private static String globalUserFacebookID;
private static String globalUserFacebookToken;
private static String globalUserFacebookPermission;

public static void setInstance(GlobalClass instance) {
    GlobalClass.instance = instance;
}

public static String getGlobalUserFirebaseName() {
    return globalUserFirebaseName;
}

public static void setGlobalUserFirebaseName(String globalUserFirebaseName) {
    GlobalClass.globalUserFirebaseName = globalUserFirebaseName;
}

public static String getGlobalUserFirebaseEmail() {
    return globalUserFirebaseEmail;
}

public static void setGlobalUserFirebaseEmail(String globalUserFirebaseEmail) {
    GlobalClass.globalUserFirebaseEmail = globalUserFirebaseEmail;
}

public static String getGlobalUserFirebasePassword() {
    return globalUserFirebasePassword;
}

public static void setGlobalUserFirebasePassword(String globalUserFirebasePassword) {
    GlobalClass.globalUserFirebasePassword = globalUserFirebasePassword;
}

public static String getGlobalUserFacebookName() {
    return globalUserFacebookName;
}

public static void setGlobalUserFacebookName(String globalUserFacebookName) {
    GlobalClass.globalUserFacebookName = globalUserFacebookName;
}

public static String getGlobalUserFacebookID() {
    return globalUserFacebookID;
}

public static void setGlobalUserFacebookID(String globalUserFacebookID) {
    GlobalClass.globalUserFacebookID = globalUserFacebookID;
}

public static String getGlobalUserFacebookToken() {
    return globalUserFacebookToken;
}

public static void setGlobalUserFacebookToken(String globalUserFacebookToken) {
    GlobalClass.globalUserFacebookToken = globalUserFacebookToken;
}

public static String getGlobalUserFacebookPermission() {
    return globalUserFacebookPermission;
}

public static void setGlobalUserFacebookPermission(String globalUserFacebookPermission) {
    GlobalClass.globalUserFacebookPermission = globalUserFacebookPermission;
}

public static synchronized  GlobalClass getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new GlobalClass();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

Comment: add code in original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [csell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454637/even-created-a-global-class-still-cannot-save-a-variable-from-try-catch#answer-48455065), which is correct, this is just a matter of scope.

You can read more [oracle's official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing) about anonymous class and the final keyword to solve your problem.

You should consider making only the field "instance" of the GlobalInstance to be static for singleton use. Others fields should be at object's instance level (non-staic) to make sure that you always use the same global variable, and you go more into abstraction/encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If an object is created inside a class then that object can only be referenced inside that class unless you create a method which returns that object. With that said, any class with access to the object can call the methods associated with that object. This does not mean the variables can be seen though. In order for the variable values to be retrieved, you must have methods returning those values, like you have in `GlobalClass`. Thus, the problem is related to scope.

Comment: @PhilipsTin You’re welcome! Remember to select an answer for future users who visit this question.